# How do I use recursion to find all the directories?

Tags: c++, windows, operating-system

I need to write code that can find the largest folder on the entire system. Including system directories such as sys.

How to find the largest folder in the system, including sys?

That is, I set the initial path to C:\\, and then the folder search should begin

The code I used to determine the size of the folder

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <filesystem>
using namespace std;
using namespace std::tr2::sys;

void  getFoldersize(string rootFolder,unsigned long long & f_size)
{
   path folderPath(rootFolder);                      
   if (exists(folderPath))
   {
        directory_iterator end_itr;
        for (directory_iterator dirIte(rootFolder); dirIte != end_itr; ++dirIte )
        {
            path filePath(complete (dirIte->path(), folderPath));
           try{
                  if (!is_directory(dirIte->status()) )
                  {
                      f_size = f_size + file_size(filePath);                      
                  }else
                  {
                      getFoldersize(filePath,f_size);
                  }
              }catch(exception& e){  cout << e.what() << endl; }
         }
      }
    }
```

Comment: But what is the question ?

Comment: I need to know how to allow a program to bypass system directories, and also how to bypass each directory in a folder.
That is, I do not need the size of the entire C directory, but only the largest folder there

Comment: @CyberMavka: Questions typically include "what", "when", "why" or "how" and end in a question mark. May we assume your question is "How do I use recursion to find all the directories?"

Comment: @Brendan Sorry this is my first question here.
Yes, that is what I would like to ask.

Comment: Please [edit] your post with the actual question(s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved my question, here is a piece of code that helps to recursively go through all the folders in the root folder and find the size of each folder separately, someone might need it.

```
std::map<std::string, intmax_t> sizeFolder;

std::uintmax_t directorySize(const std::filesystem::path& directory)
{
    std::uintmax_t size{ 0 };
    for (const auto& entry : std::filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator(directory))
    {
        if (entry.is_regular_file() && !entry.is_symlink())
        {
            size += entry.file_size();
        }
    }
    return size;
}

void ls_recursive(const std::filesystem::path& path)
{
    int_fast64_t count = 0;
    for(const auto& p: std::filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator(path,std::filesystem::directory_options::skip_permission_denied))
    {
        if (std::filesystem::is_directory(p)) 
        {
            uintmax_t temp = 0;
            temp = directorySize(p.path());
            sizeFolder[p.path().filename().string()] = temp;
        }
    }
}
```